# Truck died at light but started again once facing downhill

Tags: engine, ford, stall, f-150

I bought a 92 Ford F-150 with a 351 in it. The truck set for about a year. I mean the guy started it up every now and again but hardly ever drove it. I was taking my girlfriend to work. I pulled up to a red light and the truck died. The gas gauge read 1/2 full. I ended up pushing it off the road. I got it to a hill where the nose of the truck was facing down hill and it started up, but had a slight miss in the motor. I was wondering if anyone could tell me what's wrong? I know it's not the fuel pump because I can hear it kick on.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is the truck carbureted or fuel injected?

Comment: Is the 1/2 tank of gas the same gas that was in it for a year?

Comment: Fuel injected and no I ran all the gas out and put new gas in it